# How to replace a string in a page with Jekyll before running liquid

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I have a page `xyz.replaceme` in my root directory and it is markdown formatted like so..

```
---
layout: post
title:  "xyz"
date:   2015-01-12 15:21:30
categories: xyz
---

{{ xyz }}
```

I want to replace `{{ xyz }}` with another string, convert the file to `.md` and have it rendered like every other page. I'm trying to do this via `_plugins/converters.rb` but it just isn't working.

```
class xyz < Converter
    priority :high
    safe true
    def matches(ext)
      ext =~ /^\.replaceme$/i
    end
    def output_ext(ext)
      ".md"
    end
    def convert(content)
      content.gsub('{{ xyz }}', 'abc')
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The liquid output markup `{{ xyz }}` only works with a YAML front-matter.